# Grouping multiple dates from json in klipfolio

Tags: klipfolio

I have a JSON formatted input in the below form:

```
[
  {
    "hash":"abcdefg",
    "Stage 1 Status":"Complete",
    "Stage 1 Completion":"2021-01-16T19:56:10+02:00",
    "Stage 2 Status":"Complete",
    "Stage 2 Completion":"2021-02-17T16:30:30+03:00",
    "Stage 3 Status":"Complete",
    "Stage 3 Completion":"2021-03-17T16:30:34+03:00"
  },
  {
    "hash":"klmnop",
    "Stage 1 Status":"Complete",
    "Stage 1 Completion":"2021-01-16T19:56:10+02:00",
    "Stage 2 Status":"Open",
    "Stage 2 Completion":"2021-02-17T16:30:34+03:00"
  },
  {
    "hash":"jklmn",
    "Stage 1 Status":"Complete",
    "Stage 1 Completion":"2021-01-16T19:56:10+02:00",
    "Stage 2 Status":"Lost",
    "Stage 2 Completion":"2021-07-17T16:30:30+03:00"
  }
]
```

And I want to make a klip in klifolio, Showing me the Completed stages of each month like the below output derived from the above data.

|  | January | February | March |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Stage1 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| Stage2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| Stage3 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

The data is of three years and I need to show the years counts in separate tables.
New to klipfolio so till now I have constructed arrays for table column titles and row tags, but I am having difficulty with the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this in Klipfolio, you'll need to first organize your JSON data into columnar structures so you can perform queries on it. To do this you need one set of data for the status, completion and stage name.

1. For the stage name, you can utilize [kf:names](https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/articles/215547118-About-JSON-and-XML-data-sources#xpathFunctions) and the [LEFT()](https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011416893-Klipfolio-functions?query=left#LEFT) function. This will look like:

   `LEFT(@kf:names(/,FALSE),7)`

By default, kf:names returns data in alphabetical order, and the FALSE parameter return the data in the order from top to bottom of the JSON structure.

LEFT() will return the 7 leftmost characters, which will only return "Stage 1" instead of "Stage 1 Status"

2. To return the date, the wildcard selector is needed as well as the contains() function to return any values for the fields that have the name the contains "Completion".

   `@/*[contains(name(),'Completion')]`
3. Finally, to return the status you'll need to do the same as above, but search for field names that contain "status".

   `@/*[contains(name(),'Status')]`
4. From here you should have 3 arrays of data you can query upon. The first query which returns all field names in your JSON structure will first need to be filtered to return the same amount of items as the dates and status arrays. You can use [SELECT()](https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011416893-Klipfolio-functions?query=left#SELECT) to only return fields with 'Completion' or 'Status' as we know there is a one-to-one relationship between these fields and the values.

`SELECT(LEFT(@kf:names(/,FALSE),7),CONTAINS(@kf:names(/,FALSE),"Status"))`

This will return 7 items to match the 7 items of dates and statuses.

Now that the data is in the proper shape, a [LOOKUP()](https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011416893-Klipfolio-functions?query=left#LOOKUP) can be used in each column to align the count of completed records per stage, by using the SELECT(), [AND()](https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011416893-Klipfolio-functions?query=left#AND), [GROUP()](https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011416893-Klipfolio-functions?query=left#GROUP) and [COUNTDISTINCT()](https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011416893-Klipfolio-functions?query=left#COUNTDISTINCT) functions.

First, [results reference](https://support.klipfolio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000181613-Writing-formulas-using-results-references?query=result%20reference) the column with the stage names, in the first parameter of LOOKUP(). Then use a SELECT() to filter for only the completed stages which fall in a specific month. For the dates, you'll need to convert to unix time with DATE() and then DATEVALUE() to convert to something that is rolled up to a month like "yyyyMM" format which would return "202101" if the date is in January of this year.

The SELECT() looks like this:

`SELECT(SELECT(LEFT(@kf:names(/,FALSE),7),CONTAINS(@kf:names(/,FALSE),"Status")),AND(DATEVALUE(DATE(@/*[contains(name(),'Completion')],"yyyy-MM-dd"),"yyyyMM")="202101",@/*[contains(name(),'Status')]="Complete"))`

In the second parameter wrap a GROUP() around the SELECT() to group like values and in the third parameter of the LOOKUP() wrap the SELECT() with a COUNTDISTINCT() to count the items per group. The whole formula for the January 2021 column would look like so:

`LOOKUP(&Stages,GROUP(SELECT( SELECT(LEFT(@kf:names(/,FALSE),7),CONTAINS(@kf:names(/,FALSE),"Status")), AND(DATEVALUE(DATE(@/*[contains(name(),'Completion')],"yyyy-MM-dd"),"yyyyMM")="202101", @/*[contains(name(),'Status')]="Complete"))), COUNTDISTINCT(SELECT( SELECT(LEFT(@kf:names(/,FALSE),7),CONTAINS(@kf:names(/,FALSE),"Status")), AND(DATEVALUE(DATE(@/*[contains(name(),'Completion')],"yyyy-MM-dd"),"yyyyMM")="202101", @/*[contains(name(),'Status')]="Complete"))))`

From there, you can change the 202101 in the formula to any yyyyMM to return a particular month data, IE. for the next column, February it would be 202102.

[image]

Comment: First of all thank you for your step by step reply. It's really helping me understand Klipfolio. That said, I am having trouble accessing the data through your commands except if I am not understanding the flow. The sets of data created in the first phase are placed into the final query of each column right? It doesn't need to be modeled in the import phase of the data right? Could this be attributed to the fact that the dataset (json file) has more fields but unrelated to the final outcome? Thank you so much for taking the time to explain .

Comment: More precisely, for example when I enter LEFT(@kf:names(/,FALSE),7)  to the Insert field   I get Unrecognized keyword. I am probably doing something wrong. Data source is connected in form [ { }, { }, { }, ... , { } ] as in my example. So more like an array of json files than a pure json file. Cheers again!

Comment: I think the issue is that you can't copy the formula directly from this answer as each "pill" has an underlying alphanumeric string related to which data source it's coming from. For example, if you copy the "pill" and enter it into a text editor you'll see something like 8eb198aa1efdc9c4db521039afa2747a@kf:names(/,FALSE); If the "pill" is valid, then it will be blue, but if it is red, it means it's not reading the data correctly due to syntax. Their support team is excellent so if this doesn't answer your question you can ask support at support@klipfolio.com and they'll help out. :)